# Cambiar tamaño del pdf Google Charts / JSPDF

Tags: jspdf, google-chart-api

Actualmente estoy trabajando unos graficos en google charts pero a pesar de que puedo imprimir el gráfico en pdf no logro hacerlo en las dimensiones reales del gráfico, si alguien puede orientarme cómo puedo cambiar el tamaño del pdf para que el gráfico se vea completo, dejo el código funcional para que puedan copiarlo y usarlo para sus necesidades.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(dibujarGrafico);
   function dibujarGrafico() {
     // Tabla de datos: valores y etiquetas de la gráfica
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Mes', 'Enviado'],
       ['Ene', 20.21],
       ['Feb', 4.28],
       ['Mar', 17.26],
       ['Abr', 11.25],
       ['Mayo', 14.25],
       ['Jun', 5.25],
       ['Jul', 8.15],
       ['Ago', 15.22],
       ['Sept', 4.67],
       ['Oct', 9.24],
       ['Nov', 10.05],
       ['Dic', 6.75]
     ]);
     var options = {
       title: 'Envios durante el año en curso',
       colors: ['green'],
     };
     // Dibujar el gráfico

      var container = document.getElementById('GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1');
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
     //codigo para exportar a PDF
      var btnSave = document.getElementById('save-pdf');

     google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
       btnSave.disabled = false;
     });

     btnSave.addEventListener('click', function () {
       var doc = new jsPDF();
       doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0, 0);
       doc.save('chart.pdf');
     }, false);

     //



     chart.draw(data, options);
   }
 </script>
 </head>
<input id="save-pdf" type="button" value="Exportar a PDF" disabled />
<i  aria-hidden="true"></i>
<div id="GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1" style="width: 1000px; height: 200px">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes asignarle el tamaño de la pagina pdf que desees en las opciones al crear el objeto jsPDF:

Por ejemplo:

```
new jsPDF( 'p', 'mm', [1000, 1000]);
```

Siendo el primer parametro l de 'landscape' o p de 'portrait', el segundo parametro la unidad de medida 'mm' de milimetro o 'in' de pulgadas, y el tercer parametro la altura y el ancho.

```html
  <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
           google.setOnLoadCallback(dibujarGrafico);
           function dibujarGrafico() {
             // Tabla de datos: valores y etiquetas de la gráfica
             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Mes', 'Enviado'],
               ['Ene', 20.21],
               ['Feb', 4.28],
               ['Mar', 17.26],
               ['Abr', 11.25],
               ['Mayo', 14.25],
               ['Jun', 5.25],
               ['Jul', 8.15],
               ['Ago', 15.22],
               ['Sept', 4.67],
               ['Oct', 9.24],
               ['Nov', 10.05],
               ['Dic', 6.75]
             ]);
            
             // Dibujar el gráfico

              var container = document.getElementById('GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1');
              var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
             //codigo para exportar a PDF
              var btnSave = document.getElementById('save-pdf');

             google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
               btnSave.disabled = false;
             });

             btnSave.addEventListener('click', function () {
             //ACA LE ENVIAS LOS PARAMETROS CON LAS MEDIDAS EN MILIMETROS DEL TAMAÑO DE LA PAGINA QUE DESEES
               var doc = new jsPDF( 'p', 'mm', [1000, 1000]);
               doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0, 0);
               doc.save('chart.pdf');
             }, false);

             //Le asignas el tamaño que desees
             chart.draw(data, {
        chartArea: {
          bottom: 24,
          left: 36,
          right: 12,
          top: 48,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          
        },
        height: 600,
        title: 'Envios durante el año en curso',
        width: 600,
        colors: ['green']
      });
           }
         </script>
         </head>
        <input id="save-pdf" type="button" value="Exportar a PDF" disabled />
        <i  aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div id="GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1" style="width: 1000px; height: 200px">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Las dimensiones del gráfico están bien  y no quiero modificarlas ya que necesitan estar a ese tamaño para adaparse a las ventanas del sistema. Lo que quiero es cambiar las dimensiones del pdf para que el gráfico quepa al exportarse.

Comment: Entiendo amigo solo tienes que enviarle los parametros en milimetros del tamaño de la pagina que desees:  new jsPDF( 'p', 'mm', [1000, 1000]); modfique el codigo para que lo veas enviandole 1000 por 1000 milimetros

Comment: Listo, era lo que necesitaba!